# Website Example for User Engagement for first time user

Tags: user-engagement

I would like to add step by step Login instructions for first time users on my website (like what we see in the Facebook game, show popup instruction one by one to follow).

Any website can you suggest which has this feature as reference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very general question, but I would probably set a cookie with a long expiration date when someone visits your site. From there, you can go on to display registration instructions for those that ***don't*** have the cookie set. I can't be anymore specific since you didn't mention what technology your site is built on.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this link for [Facebook FBML Tutorial - Step By Step Instructions to Adding Your FBML Tab Into Your Fan Page](http://www.articlesbase.com/finance-articles/facebook-fbml-tutorial-step-by-step-instructions-to-adding-your-fbml-tab-into-your-fan-page-3707141.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry for I didn't mentions clear enough. I edited my post, I want to create website which has guided instruction.